# FitzHugh–Nagumo system with diffusion

Tags: neurology, action-potential, systems-biology

I was studying the FitzHugh-Nagumo model with diffusion and I quite do not understand the meaning of it.

If we consider the system without diffusion,

\begin{equation}\label{FHN}\begin{cases}
\dot{u}=\mu\left( u-\frac{u^3}{3}+v+z \right), \\
\dot{v}=-\frac{1}{\mu}\left( u-a+bv \right),
\end{cases}\end{equation}

where $u=u(t)$ and $v=v(t)$, then it models the control of the electrical potential across a cell membrane. It models the action potential in neurons, for example. But this happens because in the system there is a stimulus current, $z(t)$. The system with diffusion

\begin{equation*}\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \epsilon D_u \nabla ^2u+\frac{1}{\epsilon}(u-\frac{u^3}{3}+v), \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \epsilon^2D_v \nabla ^2v-(u-a+bv),
\end{cases}\end{equation*}

where $u=u(x,y,t)$ and $v=v(x,y,t)$, models exactly the same but just adding diffusion and removing the stimulus current.

1. How can it model the same biological behaviour if the stimulus current disappears?
2. Therefore, which is the exact meaning of this sistem (the second one)?

I've implemented numerically this system, and ploting $u$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ in a specific time, I get something similar to the following images:

https://chemoton.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/fitzhugh-nagumo-type-reaction-diffusion-system-i.png

Where the first image corresponds to $t=0$, the second one $t=10$ and the last one $t=100$.

3. What does this pattern formation mean? I do not know how action potential (which is modelled in this system) is related with these images...
4. Does this happen because the activated cells activate the ones in the neighbourhood (since diffusion acts)? Or this is wrong because the system only takes into account one single neuron?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The FHN equation describes a dynamical system which is only dependent on time using a system of non-linear ordinary differential equations. When you allow diffusion (of the current) then you'll get a partial differential equation with spatial as well as temporal variable. You will get travelling waves along the spatial co-ordinates. Also have a look at the [cable equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_theory#Deriving_the_cable_equation).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The system with diffusion also models the behaviour of a single neuron, like the system without diffusion? Or it goes a step further and models a group of them?

Comment: It is also of a single neuron. Perhaps you can add details to clarify the premise of your question.

Comment: Mmmm... But in the output of the numerical implementation of the system with diffusion (the three images in the link) we observe a kind of pattern formation, which seems to represent that activated cells activate the cells near them.  Therefore, many cells should be taken into account, in this model, or not? If it only models the behavior of a single neuron, what represents the "pattern formation" of the images?

Comment: Are you talking about the wikipedia article? I am not sure what exactly you are referring to. Can you add the right reference and also include the diagram that you were talking about. AFAIK, the diffusion is within a cell.

Comment: I'm talking about the wikipedia article, right. But I've also included a link with the three images I'm referring to. I wanted to know the meaning of these images: Why do we get a pattern formation and which relation this has with the action-potential.
Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Why do you get those patterns? That's the steady state property of some of these reaction diffusion systems. You can read Alan Turing's article on the chemical basis of morphogenesis. All these images denote a 2D space. I presume that the diffusion considered for the FHN model would be 1D (action potential travels along one direction). Moreover, FHN model oscillates and the steady state behaviour of FHN+diffusion would be travelling waves. So none of these plots denote the FHN model.

Comment: I've implemented a numerical simulation of the system with diffusion and I also get plots like the ones in the link. I plot "u" (coloured) in terms of "x,y" and the output are pattern formation [x is in the x-axis, y in the y-axis and u is represented just with different colours, not in the z-axis].
I don't quite understant these images because of action potential travels in one direction, as you said. Then I don't know how to connect the meaning of the system with the output of implementing it.

Comment: You should first understand the model before simulating it. I cannot be sure what you simulated actually. This is getting into a long discussion. Please ask a precise question. As the question stands it is difficult to determine what it is actually about.

Comment: I've changed a bit the question. In fact, what I want to know is the exact meaning of the system with diffusion. Thank you!